# How can i organize a number?

Tags: java

I want to organize a number like this "999.99.999"

This number's length always 8 character.

Example

12314156 => 123.14.156

How do I format?

Comment: What have you tried? If you're expecting us to do it for you, you've come to the wrong place. I suggest you check regexes (or substring) and String format.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `format` in java just like  printf in C or even `System.out.printf` .

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize the code below.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})").matcher("99999999");
if(m.matches()){              System.out.println(m.group(1).concat(".").concat(m.group(2)).concat(".").concat(m.group(3)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string format to do what you need how to use string format is described in this link 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format